# Strange keyboard shortcut suddenly appears

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

This just happened recently and rebooting did not solve it. Suddenly, whenever I type the key combination `dt` I get the date, e.g., `2020-10-27` just now. In order for me to type those characters I now have to put a space in between them and then delete it. This happens in any context whether it is a text editor, the command line, or any app. I checked all the keyboard shortcuts in Preferences and there is no such combination. There are no aliases for it. What could be causing this? OS x 10.8.5.

Comment: See this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/404792/119271

Comment: But that answer says `Text Replacements work on apps that utilize the Cocoa interface. This means any Apple application and any third party app like Chrome, will have text Replacements compatability.` and then recommends third party apps to better control the replacement triggering, assuming that text replacement shortcuts are already configured in keyboard settings. There is no way I could have done that since there is no tab that allows that. All of the shortcuts in Settings have modifier keys before a character.

[Keyboard Preferences.png](https://postimg.cc/YvX9gSY2)

Comment: It's not a Keyboard Shortcut.  It's "Text Replacements."  What version of macOS are you using?  Because mine's slightly different.  Try "Keyboard & Text" in the left box.  Also, see this:  https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/replace-text-punctuation-documents-mac-mh35735/mac

Comment: Just saw that you're using Mountain Lion.  It's called "Text Substitutions"  See this article:  https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/mountain-lions-new-text-substitutions/

Comment: Thing is… Text Replacement can't do "today's date" [I wish it could] so it has to be something 3rd party. What have you installed recently?

Comment: @Allan

Thanks. I did not know about that, though typing 1/2 does get replaced by ½, etc. But no custom entries.

Comment: @Tetsujin

Yeah, looks like it can only replace with characters and symbols. Is it something 3rd party or possibly malware? I'll have to see what I installed before this happened. That may take some time. What kind of apps could do this? I've installed latest python3 and other cli tools.

Comment: What is most peculiar is that this substitution even works in a plain text editor, not just a rich text one.

Comment: idk what might be the cause, I don't use 'dev tools' of any sort, so I've no experience with anything like that, sorry. I just knew it couldn't be the system… as it's a feature I've wanted for years ;)

Comment: I just use a bash script in `/usr/local/bin/`, which is in my path. `ymd.sh`: `ymd=\`date "+%Y-%m-%d"\` echo echo $ymd echo echo -n $ymd | pbcopy` I added a symlink to it in a separate directory that is also in my path so all I have to do is type `ymd` at a command prompt and the date is in my clipboard. `~ $ ymd` 2020-10-28